# apparmor deny icmp issue

Tags: linux, apparmor

## Problem

AppArmor provides a way to block network traffic using network rules such as:

```
deny network udp
deny network tcp
deny network icmp
```

`udp`, `tcp`, works fine but `icmp` does not work.

Additionally for `icmp` I tried (in vain):

```
deny network inet icmp
deny network dgram icmp      [apparmor_parser reports error for this rule]
deny network raw
deny network packet
```

However, if I try `deny network udp` or `deny network dgram`, it blocks both `icmp`, and `udp`.

When I checked the socket calls from the ping utility, I found following (using `strace ping -c1 8.8.8.8`):

```
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMPV6) = 4
...
```

## Expectation

What AppArmor rule can be used to block ICMP traffic?

## Settings

- AppArmor version: 3.0.4
- Distro: Ubuntu 22.04
- Util emitting ICMP traffic: ping